# How to show administrative shares in Windows Server 2012's Server Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share

How do I make **default administrative shares** visible in *File and Storage Services*, in the Windows Server 2012 *Server Manager*?

With the *Computer Management* MMC add-in all shares hosted by a server are visible, hidden or otherwise. This is true when connecting remotley, you can right-click on `C$` and choose *Open* to connect to `\\SERVER\C$`. However the *Server Manager* interface shows only non-default shares, and I can't find how to make C$ etc visible.

This is a minor irritation; it's an insconsistent design but not otherwise a problem.

Comment: Why do you call it inconsistent design? Just because **you** want to see it in Server Manager doesn't mean that Microsoft wants you to see it there. Server Manager presents what it was designed to present. Server Manager isn't a tool that was intended to be used to manage the default hidden shares, probably because those hidden shares aren't "user facing" and don't directly provide services to end users. As it stands, you can't make them visible in Server Manager because Server Manager isn't a tool for managing those hidden shares and the UI has no mechanism by which to present them to you.

Comment: If the Computer Management console and the Server Manager console had the same design goals and the same intended use then I'd call that inconsistent design, but they don't so it's not.

Comment: It's inconsistent because the feature was present in the previous MMC incarnation. The current Server Manager would seem to be geared towards remote management of your server farm, and this information is missing. But whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will show all shares on the machine including administrative shares.

```
net share
```

Comment: Yes, but doesn't answer the question at all. Can you update your answer or consider removing it?